# What is meant by "pseudo forces are mathematical corrections in non-inertial frames"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

I have read in several posts that "pseudo forces are mathematical corrections in non-inertial frames" that enable Newton's second law to hold true. How is this "correction" related to newton's second law?

Comment: Please add a reference.

Comment: @my2cts yes, that seems confusing. Changed it

Answer (score 4):

The people who say this are wrong. Pseudoforces are not mathematical. They are physical. In an *inertial* frame they do not exist, but there are many cases where a non-inertial frame is more convenient. In Newton gravity, free fall defines a non-inertial frame in which the falling object is at rest and a pseudoforce exactly cancels gravity. This is a very convenient frame when you are aboard the ISS. Also on a merry go round or in a roller coaster the non-inertial frame is more convenient.